# How to fix : Blank Space In Right Side Of Layout

Tags: html, css

I was working on responsive website but some error appeared . white space in my right side of my mobile version cant be deleted.

I Tried With overflow-x:hidden and width:100%:
but no one working

Comment: Please show your working code, we're unable to help without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll down and check which container is causing an overflow of the width. In most of the cases it is images, try setting the max-width: 100% for images and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you So much! it Worked! but 
unfortunately i cant ask question anymore..im banned XD thanks dude u save my day